# How to prove a norm on three dimensional space

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $||(x,y,z)||=|x| + 2 \sqrt{(y^2+z^2)}$ is a norm on $\mathbb R^3 $. Sketch the unit ball.

I have to show the positiveness, homogeneity and triangle inequality of the equation.

So notice that $|x| + x \sqrt{y^2+z^2)} = 0$ iff $ ||x || = 0$, $ ||y|| = 0$ and $ ||z|| = 0$.Hence it satifies the postive definiteness of the norm.

Suppose $ \alpha \in \mathbb R$, then $$ ||\alpha (x,y,z)|| = \alpha [|x| + 2 \sqrt{(y^2+z^2)}] = |\alpha| ||(x,y,z)||$$ Hence it satisfies the nomogeneity.

But I got stuck how to show triangle inequality for 3 variables. Also, I need help for sketching the unit ball.

Please guide me to finish the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the unit ball, think about what happens when $x = 0$, $x = \pm x_0$. Not a sphere, but two ____.

Comment: How do i prove triangle inequality for the equation? thanks!

Comment: Triangle inequality is below. For the unit ball, one more hint to develop an intuition for what is going on: let $y = 0$. What is the set of points for which $||(x,y,z)|| = 1$? I.e., for $||(x,0,z)|| = 1$.

Comment: If I set $x=0$, then I get $ z = \sqrt {1-y^2} $ or $y=\sqrt {1-z^2}$. If i set $y=0$, i get $z=(1-x)/2$ and if i set $z=0$, i get $y=(1-x)/2$. Then how do i sketh the ball? Thanks for the hints!

Comment: Thus in the $yz$ plane ($x = 0$) we have a circle. But in the $xz$ plane ($y = 0$) you have $|x| + |z| = 1$, a diamond of straight lines.  Similarly in the $xy$ plane ($z = 0$) we have another diamond, $|x| + |y| = 1$. Finally observe that whatever the unit ball is, it must be symmetric about the $x$-axis, as $y^2 + z^2$ is invariant under rotations about that axis. Hence ...

Comment: Thanks! On the x-axis, the length from the origin is $ |1| $ and on the y- and z- axes, the length from the origin is $ |0.5| $. How do I sketch that on the 3D plane?

Comment: would that be diamond then? How did you get those distances? When i set $ x = 0 $, I get $ y^2 + z^2 = 1/4$, hence I get $y = |0.5|$ when $ z= 0$ and vice versa. Then when i set $y=0$, i get $|x| + 2 \sqrt (z^2) = 1$ then i get $ x = 1$ and $z=0.5$, and same story for $|x| + 2 \sqrt (y^2) = 1$ when i set $z = 0$. Thank you so much for hints so far!

Comment: It's two cones joined together at a circle in the $x = 0$ plane, i.e., $yz$ plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the triangle inequality, you have to prove:
$$\lvert x+x'\rvert+2\sqrt{(y+y')^2+(z+z')^2}\leq\lvert x\rvert+2\sqrt{y^2+z^2}+\lvert x'\rvert+2\sqrt{y'^2+z'^2}$$
This amounts to proving:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{(y+y')^2+(z+z')^2}&\leq \sqrt{y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{y'^2+z'^2}\\
\iff(y+y')^2+(z+z')^2&\leq y^2+z^2+y'^2+z'^2+2 \sqrt{y^2+z^2}\sqrt{y'^2+z'^2}\\
\iff\phantom{(y+y')^2+(z+z')^2}\llap{yy'+zz'}&\leq\sqrt{y^2+z^2}\sqrt{y'^2+z'^2}
\end{align*}
This is simply *Cauchy-Schwarz*'s inequality.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I got it. Any suggestion for sketching the ball?